# What is $P_X (X = i)$, i ≥ 1?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let the vase contain two balls - red and blue. At each step, a ball is randomly removed from the vase and two others of the same color are placed in its place. For example, if a red ball is removed at the first step, then there will be two red balls and one blue ball in the vase. Let X = "the number of the step at which the blue ball was first drawn." For example, if a red ball is drawn in the first step, and a blue ball is drawn in the second, then X = 2.

(a) What is $P_X (X = i)$, i ≥ 1?

(b)Show that sooner or later the blue ball will still be drawn, i.e. that $Р_х(Х<\infty)=1$ (I don’t even have guesses here)

My reasoning was as follows: at first I thought that to find the probability, all possible options can be written down as the sum of an arithmetic progression, then the question arose of how to write down the possible options for pulling out a blue ball. The very probability depends on X and this drove me to a dead end. Most likely, a discrete distribution is involved here....hmmm...Please help me.

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "Why is $P_x(X=i), i≥1$? " mean?  Seems like you forgot to include the actual question.

Comment: Anna made it clear that it is the probability.

Comment: This was a real question. This is the transcript - What is the probability of drawing a blue ball in the vase at the corresponding step? Let's denote the X-step number as i

Comment: Here it is also necessary to determine the distribution of the quantity X(i)

Comment: So...did you mean to write "*What* is $P_X(X=i)$?"  I really don't understand the "Why".

Comment: Write out $P(X=1),$ $P(X=2),$ and so on, then observe the cancellation that takes place between certain numerators and denominators. This will help you generalize to $P(X=i)$ for $i=1,2,\dots$ That will start with the first part.

Comment: If you want to compute $P_X(X=i)$, I first suggest doing it for small $i$.  This is easy for $i=1$, what about $i=2$?  $i=3$?  Then a simple recursion should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, I think I misunderstood the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Using a telescoping product, we get that $P_X(X ≤ i)$ = $\frac{i}{i+1}$. Since this tends to 1, $P_X(X < \infty)$ = 1.  By taking the difference of two such terms, we get that $P_X(X = i)$ = $\frac{1}{i(i+1)}$.